# Why does iOS Release not work, but Debug builds are okay?

Tags: ios, build, release

Debug builds are perfect, but when I switch to Release, the app shows up on iPhone missing parts, like icons, text, and UI items.  Do you know what to do, because you've had this problem and fixed it?  I've tried all the expected, like cleaning build folder, deleting DerivedData, deleting app on iPhone, reboot iPhone, reboot Mac, etc.  Is there something I need to delete in Xcode that's not cleared by Clear Build Folder or DerivedData?  Other ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you share some code with some screenshots showing which portions work in debug build and not in release?

Comment: Um, that would be a bit too much disclosure. If there’s no general problem, there won’t be a known specific solution.  It did seem to start with the latest update. But thanks for asking.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I will presume I have the answer.  The behavior is repeatable: Debug and Release -O2 are fine, Release -O3 and above are not.  I probably have a memory release bug that is being masked by Debug and Release -O2.